# Partition of a set identified by a equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

How can I do this?

For each integer $a> 1$, $σ (a)$ is the smallest prime number dividing $a$. Fix

$$S := \{10, 11, 12,. . . , 24, 25\}$$

Consider the equivalence relation $R$ defined in $S$ placing

$$a R b \Leftrightarrow σ (a) = σ (b).$$

> Find the partition of $S$ identified by $R$

My attempt:

$\{\{10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24\},\{15,21\},\{25\},\{11\},\{13\},\{17\},\{19\},\{23\}\}$

Comment: OK, so what is the smallest prime number dividing $10$? It's 2. What's the smallest dividing $11$? It's $11$ itself. For $12$ it's $2$, and of course for all even numebrs it's $2$. So, we have that all even numbers are in one equivalence class, namely the class of all numbers whose smallest prime divisor is $2$.  We also have one where the smallest prime divisor is $3$, which includes the numbers $15$ and $21$.   ... Do you now see what you need to do?

Comment: @Bram28 Look at my attempt

Comment: @Jonsa It's fine.

Comment: Your last line would be correct if you put in some set-brackets { ..... } because there are 8 separate sets.

Comment: Now it's fine...................

Comment: @Jonsa Yes, good job!

Answer (score 1):

If the least prime factor of $n$ is $\ge 7$ and $n$ is composite then $n\ge 7^2=49$. Hence, we have to consider as representative elements only: prime numbers, and the ones with least prime factors $2,3,$ and $5$ (let's us say $A,B,C$, respectively). Then
$$
A=\{10,12,14,\ldots,24\}, B=\{15, 21\}, \text{ and } C=\{25\}.
$$
To these three classes, we should add:
$$
\{11\}, \{13\}, \{17\}, \{19\}, \text{ and } \{23\}.
$$

Conclusion: your attempt is correct.